# Refinery CMS and Extensions with Migrations. Anything I should know?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration, refinerycms

I've inherited a rails web application that has Refinery CMS as the root app with multiple apps under the `/vendor/extensions` directory. The applications under this directory have database migrations under their `db` directory.

Currently, this project is not completing its `rake db:migrate` command because its expecting a table to exist that doest and its trying to rename a column on this table. I believe I've determined that there is in fact no migration for creating this table in either the `db/migrate` directory of the root app (Refinery CMS) or any of the extension apps `(/vendor/extenstions/*/db/migrate)`.

I'll need to contact the previous developer probably but this still doesnt answer a question I have about Refinery CMS and Extensions:

**Is there anything special I need to do to get the migrations under the extensions directory to run?**

Comment: Did you inherit the Git repo and history with the app? You could look at the history of the `db/schema.rb` file for clues. The `db/schema.rb` will include the extension migrations.

Comment: I've received a zip file for now but thats a great idea. I have looked in the `schema.rb` file and it does have the table I'm looking for so I can at least recreate a migration and fix the problem.